# apoc.import.json NullPointerException in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to import this [JSON file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MVMAZbrl_nIGruoUsLOkcrw1jcgRli-U/view?usp=sharing) and automatically create nodes out of it but I am getting the following error,

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.import.json`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My command,
`CALL apoc.import.json('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MVMAZbrl_nIGruoUsLOkcrw1jcgRli-U')`

When locally saved inside import,
`CALL apoc.import.json('business_types (1).json')`

**Refer this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NAelpPjU9r6rDPPsKJPTbikC0U5-HOZQ/view?usp=sharing) to check indented format of the given file.**

#### JSON Format:

```
{
    "B2B": [
        {
            "q04ijnd6wjkcgg1cnyq04ijnd0kj42py": [
                "mumbai",
                "lucknow",
                "delhi"
             ]
         }
     ],
    "B2C": [
        {
            "q04ijnd6wjkcgg1cnyq04ijnd0kj42py": [
                "mumbai",
                "lucknow",
                "delhi"
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

#### Output Expected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function apoc.import.json does not allow that filename. After downloading the file locally, change it to business_types.json then try again.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///business_types.json")
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

See result below:
[image]

Comment: I understand, it's reading the file all well after renaming. But that's not my concern. I WANT TO LOAD THE NODES the way I showed in the image. Please let me know if you have a solution to load the nodes in a way I mentioned in the image.

Comment: I fixed java.lang.NullPointerException, so pls accept the answer then post another question on the data output that you want.

Comment: Okay, I'll open another question. But can I expect an answer for that? If so, please start working on it already, I'll get the question ready. As soon as I get a reply here, I'll post the link.